# Register class to specific instance

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am trying to register a class to a specific instance.

I have the following class:

```cs
public class Repository : IRepository
{
 public Repository(ICache cache, ILogger logger) 
 {
   _cache = cache;
   _logger = logger;
 }
}
```

There are two instances of ICache: `MemoryCache` and `DbCache`. I want it to always register `DbCache` to `Repository`.

Here is the code where I try to register the instance to the class.

```cs
var builder - new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register((c, p) => 
 new Repository(p.Named<ICache>("cache"), p.Named<ILogger>("logger")));

builder.RegisterAssemblyModulesInDirectoryOf(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
 .WhereFileMatches("Something.*.dll");

var container = builder.Build();

container.Resolve<IRepository>(new NamedParameter("cache", new DBCache()),
                new NamedParameter("logger", new Logger()));
```

Currently, DbCache is only loaded when the first instance of Repository is made. However, after that, new Repository instances uses MemoryCache. I want it so that whenever a Repository instance is made only DbCache is used.

Comment: [This is an FAQ in the documentation.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Comment: I followed option 2, but now it won't even load the instance I want (DbCache). It always defaults to MemoryCache for some reason.

Comment: Could you share how you register your `ICache` type ?